# Base form or gerund: "Curricula should keep up with rapid changes in education, instil/instilling values… and enlighten individuals…"

Tags: word-choice, infinitive-vs-gerund, parallelism

I wrote this sentence. My teacher corrected it to me. I used instilling instead of "instill". Can anyone help why "instill" correct and "instilling" incorrect?

> Curricula should keep up with rapid changes in education, instill values that cultivate proud citizenship and enlighten individuals to be broad-minded and well read.

Comment: As written, it's part of a coordination of three VPs serving as complement of "should, thus "Curricula should [keep up with rapid changes in education,] i[nstil values that cultivate proud citizenship[ and [enlighten individuals to be broad-minded and well read]. Since "should" is a modal auxiliary verb, it must be followed by clauses headed by the plain form of the verb (not an _ing_ form), in this case the verbs "keep", "instil" and "enlighten".

Comment: I think the syntax is inherently ambiguous. The final *and **enlighten individuals...*** could be parallel to preceding *[should] **keep up...*** and ***...instill values...*** (i.e. - enlightening is *another* thing that curricula ***should do***). OR it could adjectivally modify ***values*** (that cultivate citizenship AND enlighten individuals). And if there are only 2 things you should do, I don't think it's automatically invalid not to separate them by the word "and" - *You should **drive** carefully, **stay** alert* seems okay to me, and the same basic parsing can apply above.

Comment: use instil and enlighten OR instilling and enlightening. I'd bet you are less than 20 years old. Am I right? Cheers. :)

Comment: @Rafeq Since it was you who wrote the sentence, you should tell us what you intended it to mean. Are you saying that the instilling of values that cultivate proud citizenship is a **consequence** of curricula keeping up with rapid changes in education, or that curricula should keep up with rapid changes in education **and** instil values that cultivate proud citizenship? The punctuation seems to indicate the latter interpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can't you write simpler sentences? Even I have to read them two or three times to get your point(s).

Comment: @Lambie: I'm surprised someone like you should even need to read beyond the first sentence - "the syntax is inherently ambiguous". Obviously the default parsing would see OP's text as a "parallel" construction with ***keep up..., instill..., enlighten...*** as being the 3 things curricula should do. As soon as *that* parsing is discarded, it should be easy to see the alternative parsing whereby the *[instilled] **values*** do two things - ***cultivate...*** and ***enlighten...***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see no issue with keep up, instill and enlighten or the ing versions for the last two. But I see it could go more than one way. There are different ways to write the sentence. That doesn't make one wrong and one right.

Comment: I never suggested one was wrong and one right. The precise opposite, in fact, since I explicitly made the point before anyone else that the cited text is *ambiguous* as written, AND can be validly parsed with both infinitive and continuous ***instill / instilling***.

Answer (score 1):

I add brackets to show that the teacher's version is possible.  The sentence has a series of 3 verb phrases which are parallel:

> Curricula should [keep up with rapid changes in education], [instil values that cultivate proud citizenship] and [enlighten individuals to be broad-minded and well read].

Edit After @FumbleFingers' Comment

OP's version (before correction by the teacher) in fact is also possible. The  sentence could be parsed as

> Curricula should keep up with rapid changes in education, **instilling** values that [[cultivate proud citizenship] and [enlighten individuals to be broad-minded and well read]].

*values* is now modified by the relative clause as bracketed.

The teacher must have missed this point, thinking that parallelism would be lost if the 2nd phrase is converted to the gerund-participial form.

A 3rd possible version is to use both **instilling** and **enlightening**, and the entire bracketed portion
becomes a compound gerund-participle phrase.

> Curricula should keep up with rapid changes in education, [**instilling** values that cultivate proud citizenship and **enlightening** individuals to be broad-minded and well read].

Comment: You've flagged your second example with '*' to indicate "invalid", but I don't think it is. It can be validly parsed as saying curricula should do two things - keep up and instill values. Specifically, values that do two things - cultivate citizenship and enlighten individuals.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes, you're right.  I have edited my answer.   Hence, both the OP and the teacher are right.

Comment: I think it's important to point out that while all three of these sentences are grammatically valid, all three mean different things. I think it's likely that the intended meaning is the first, but without the OP specifying it's impossible to say. It may be that the OP's error wasn't grammar, but substance.

Answer (score 1):

> *Curricula should* [*keep up with rapid changes in education*], [*instil*
> *values that cultivate proud citizenship*] and [*enlighten individuals to*
> *be broad-minded and well read*].

As presented, the more salient interpretation of the sentence is that it consists of a coordination of three verb phrases, bracketed, each serving as complement of "should.

Since "should" is a modal auxiliary verb, it must be followed by clauses headed by the plain form of the verb (not an *ing* form), in this case the verbs "keep", "instil" and "enlighten".

Comment: Are you saying this isn't a valid sentence? *You **should** proceed with caution, **keeping** your eyes open.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Of course, "Curricula should keep up with rapid changes in education, instilling values that cultivate proud citizenship and enlightening individuals to be broad-minded and well read" is also fine. Why don't you write your own answer? One is not really superior to the other. This parse is, as it stands, fine.